# Fractional linear transformation sketching and determining sets

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm supposed to find a fractional linear transformation $f$ such that $f(0)=0$,$f(1)=3+3i$ and $f(2)=3-3i$

I got $f(z)=\frac{6z}{z(1+3i)-4i}$ by using (cross ratio)

how would I sketch and determine the sets $f(\mathbb{R}*)$,$f(i\mathbb{R}*)$,$f(y=\frac{1}{3}x)$(supposed to be curly brackets inside this) and inverse $f(\mathbb{R}*)$,$f(i\mathbb{R}*)$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}*$?

Comment: the star means that we add the point $\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a linear fractional transformation takes lines and circles to lines and circles, and is determined by its action on three points on a line or circle.  For example, we know that $(0)=0 ,(1)=3+3, (2)=3−3$ so that $f(\mathbb{R}^*)$ contains the points $0,3\pm i$.  Since these points aren't collinear, $f(\mathbb{R}^*)$ is the circle containing those points, that is, $|z-3|=3$.  For the other two lines, just pick three convenient points on each.

If by "inverse $f(\mathbb{R}^*)$" you mean $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^*)$, just solve for $f^{-1}$, which is also a linear fractional transformation, and then do the same thing.